# unable to create PVC after upgrading cluster to 1.23

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I upgraded an EKS from 1.20 to 1.23 and then created the EBS CSI driver.  (according to the instructions I should have done this step prior to upgrading)
After the upgrade existing volumes are fine, but any new volume I attempt to create they get stuck in a pending state.  When I do a describe on the pvc, this is the error message I keep getting.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/csi-iam-role.html

```
Warning  ProvisioningFailed  44s  ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gp2": rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy": could not create volume in EC2: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials
caused by: InvalidIdentityToken: No OpenIDConnect provider found in your account for https://oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/123456788990
           status code: 400, request id: 60739110-15b6-4e53-9e5b-zzzzzzzzzzzz
```

I have checked that provider shows up in the cluster using the following command

```
aws eks describe-cluster --name cluster_name --query "cluster.identity.oidc.issuer" --output text

aws iam list-open-id-connect-providers | grep EXAMPLED539D4633E53DE1B716D3041E (where EXAMPLED539D4633E53DE1B716D3041E == $Value_from_previous_command)
```

I have restarted the ebs-csi-controller deployments as per the instructions and then deleted the pvc and recreated it, but still gettting the same results.

This is the settings my StorageClass is set to

```
NAME                PROVISIONER             RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
gp2 (default)       kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   Delete          Immediate           false                  2y254d
```

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: The provider reported in InvalidIdentityToken error; is the same provider got listed in the output of `aws iam list-open-id-connect-providers`?

Comment: did you already correctly configure the IRSA for the ebs-csi-controller?